# Why does my moment.js not calculate time in different timezone based on given timestamp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

I'm getting time from the server in GMT+0 (greenwich mean time). Based on that I want to calculate and display time in Chicago. I wrote a javascript:

```
function updateTime() {
    var chicago = moment(1443646527).tz("America/Chicago").format('h:mm:ss A');
    $('#time').html(chicago + ", ");
};

moment.tz.add('America/Chicago|CST CDT|60 50|01010101010101010101010|1BQU0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0');

updateTime();
setInterval(function () {
    updateTime();
}, 1000);
```

and in that javascript given timestamp equals:

```
 GMT: Wed, 30 Sep 2015 20:55:27 GMT
```

So why on output am I getting 11:00:46 AM instead of 3:55 PM that should be in Chicago now?

Comment: Since you are showing a fixed input, the `setInterval` call doesn't really do anything, or add to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a plain number into the moment constructor, it expects that to be in terms of *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch.  The value you gave as an example would appear to be in terms of *seconds*.

You can do either one of these:

```
// multiply by 1000
moment(1443646527 * 1000).tz("America/Chicago").format('h:mm:ss A')
```

Or:

```
// use the unix function
moment.unix(1443646527).tz("America/Chicago").format('h:mm:ss A')
```

With either, you will get the expected answer `"3:55:27 PM"`.